# how to know my app's AudioRecord permission is disallowed or not

Tags: android

My app's record audio permission was disallowed by user.The problem is some android os devices `audio_recorder.getRecordingState()` always returns `AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING`.It's not a right result.

How can I know the record audio permission is available ?

```
public final class MtAudioRecord {

private static final String TAG = "audioRecord";
private static MtAudioRecord instance = null;
public static int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;// default 44100
public static final int CHANNEL_CONFIG = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
public static final int AUDIO_FORMAT = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
public static final int AUDIO_SOURCE = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;

private AudioRecord mAudioRecord;
private final int minBufferSize;
private boolean isRecording = true;
private static short[] audioData = null;

public static final MtAudioRecord getInstance() {
    if (null == instance) {
        instance = new MtAudioRecord();
    }
    return instance;
}

public MtAudioRecord() {
    minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNEL_CONFIG, AUDIO_FORMAT);
    if (minBufferSize == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
    } else if (minBufferSize == AudioRecord.ERROR) {
    } else {
        mAudioRecord =
            new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize);
    }
    audioData = new short[minBufferSize];
}

public synchronized void start() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(null != mAudioRecord){
                if (mAudioRecord.getRecordingState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Mic didn't successfully initialized");
                    return;
                }
                mAudioRecord.startRecording();
                Log.e(TAG, "recording state = " + mAudioRecord.getRecordingState());
                if (mAudioRecord.getRecordingState() != AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Mic is in use and can't be accessed");
                    return;
                }
                isRecording = true;
                while (isRecording && null != mAudioRecord) {
                    if (null == audioData) {
                        audioData = new short[minBufferSize];
                    }
                    final int read_distance = mAudioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);
                    if (read_distance == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION || read_distance == AudioRecord.ERROR || read_distance == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                        isRecording = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (mAudioRecord != null) {
                    mAudioRecord.stop();
                    mAudioRecord.release();
                    mAudioRecord = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    isRecording = false;
}
```

}

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the `AudioManager` instead. This helps you to check if the microphone was muted by the user. The method you're probably search is `isMicrophoneMute()` which returns boolean.

Here is the link for the AudioManager in android developer site. [Android Audio Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)

and the function description is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isMicrophoneMute())

and your toast is incorrect, it should be :

```
Toast.makeText(applicationContext(),"The microphone is 
                                   disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Update:**
   you can use `Context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(String permission);`

permission is the string that describes the permission you need: `android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO`

it should return integer result which is PERMISSION_GRANTED or PERMISSION_DENIED

look here for the description in android developers site : [check permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkCallingOrSelfPermission(java.lang.String))

for example :

```
public boolean checkRecordingPermission()
{
    String permission = "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO";
    int result  = getContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
    return (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
```

Comment: Thank you first, but 'AudioManager isMicrophoneMute()' return 'false'.So this way is not the best. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: you want to check if the microphone is turn off and then to turn it on from the app?

Comment: Sorry, I edited this question again.Please have a look. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi,I do this but it also returns 'PERMISSION_GRANTED'. Because I had defined the 'record audio' permission in my AndroidMainfest.xml.Do you know a device called "Xiao MI"?

Comment: No, I don't .. but it doesn't matter, Android is Android in all devices :) When you define a permission in the Manifest file its already granted.. and because of it, it will return you "TRUE"