# Check microphone permission on android

Tags: android, permissions, microphone

I have a talking app and it crashes on certain devices like Lenovo tablets. 
It throws this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
android.media.AudioRecord.<init>(AudioRecord.java:233)
org.fmod.a.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Today, I finaly got Lenovo tablet and saw this:

[image: Screenshot]

If the user doesn't click on allow, the app crashes.
On all other devices that I tested this dialog, it isn't shown and microphone works automatically.

Is there a way to check if the user has allowed microphone permission?

Comment: Android is introducing permission to APP LEVEL. This link will answer you. http://lifehacker.com/android-4-3-will-include-options-to-control-individual-921691526

Comment: have you added permission on your manifest ?

Comment: See this example : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25640567/4385913

Comment: @Duggu I have permission in manifest, and it works on a lot of devices. It only crashes on some devices that have this permission controll when user clicks deny.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain I suspected that they added this permission controll, but my question is - Is there a way to check if someone clicked deny so I can disable microphone and show them some dialog to tell them that next time they should click allow?

Answer (score 1):

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission 
      android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

for more detail you must have to read below link:-

http://www.grokkingandroid.com/recording-audio-using-androids-mediarecorder-framework/